# Apply one of two decorators according to a condition in Python

Tags: python, decorator

I want to do something like

```
if a:
  dec = decorator_1
else:
  dec = decorator_2

@dec
def foo():
  pass
```

possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as the `if` statement and assignment is evaluated before the function definition.

For instance, your code as written above will work, but the following will not:

```
def bar():
  global dec
  if a:
    dec = decorator_1
  else:
    dec = decorator_2

@dec
def foo():
  pass

bar()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have will work, but I'd recommend implementing it a different way:

```
def dec(f):
    return decorator_1(f) if a else decorator_2(f)

@dec
def foo():
  print 'foo'
```

Since this does the same thing without the conditional definition. Taking it a step further, an even cleaner way that avoids referring to a global variable could be defined like this:

```
def dec(a):
    return decorator_1 if a else decorator_2

@dec(a)
def foo():
  print 'foo'
```